# Azure - run a WCF service as a WebJob

Tags: c#, azure, wcf, asp.net-web-api, azure-webjobs

I have a Web API which sends requests to a WCF server. The WCF project is being started using TopShelf.

My plan is to publish both API and WCF into Azure. 
For that I created an App Service in the cloud and published the Web API in the app service.

The WCF was publised as a WebJob because I need it to run continuously however I get this error:

Topshelf.Hosts.ConsoleRunHost Error: 0 : An exception occurred, System.ServiceModel.AddressAlreadyInUseException

Is this because the Web API and WCF are sharing the same app service?

I don't know if this is the right approach or do I really need a VM for that?

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can't expose the WCF projects TCP-ports to outside, as App Service only supports 80 and 443 for Internet facing connections. But inside the App Service you should be able to open a custom socket and to use that to communicate between the services.

The best place for the documentation is available from here:

https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#network-endpoint-listening

Couple things you could check:

1. Make sure that the WCF project is using a custom TCP port (not 80, 443)
2. Are you running in a shared plan?

If you can't get this to work and if you don't want to use Azure's IaaS solution (virtual machines) and prefer PaaS, you could check Azure Service Fabric. You should be quite easily to create a Service Fabric application using your two services.

Comment: Thanks, I checked and my WCF service is using port 50001 so that sholuldn't be a problem. I don't need to access the WCF directly from the internet, that's why I have the Web API for.
The Web API can be loaded without a problem however calls to WCF are not passing through when in Azure.
Also, I am not running the WCF in a shared plan.